# Can I say "I (have) dropped the chair"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs

If I accidentally pushed a chair and it fell down on the floor (it is no longer in the upright position), can I say "I (have) dropped the chair" or I should use another verb for that?

Comment: We don't usually drop chairs; we drop balls instead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several verbs you can use to describe the action that was performed:

- tip over
- push over
- knock over
- knock down
- push down
- capsize (metaphorically)
- roll over
- fell (archaic, usually used with trees or foes)

Drop would only be accurate if it was held up and it fell down (as opposed to being up*right* and falling over).

Comment: Good round-up!  “I knocked the chair over” seems to me the most natural here.  Both *tip over* and *push over*, to my ear, suggest that it was deliberate unless stated otherwise (so with them you’d probably say “I accidentally pushed the chair over”, as @mplungjan suggests); whereas *knock over* has more connotation of being accidental by default.

Comment: @PLL: Agreed. *Knocked over* would be my phrasal verb of choice here.

Comment: @PLL glad to be of assistance :| I used pushed because that was the word of choice in the original question. Tipping a chair needs longer contact than pushing or knocking it over

Comment: capsize would earn you some confused stares, though everything else is accurate.

Comment: @Neil: I'm sure I'd only use the word "capsize" if my audience would understand. They wouldn't be confused at all. They might still stare though. :)

Answer (score 4):

No. A better statement is:

> I (accidentally) pushed/knocked the chair *over*.

If you were carrying the chair from one end of the room to the other, and dropped it, you could use your statement.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with *drop* here is that it implies you were holding it up in the first place and your action/inaction led to its falling to the floor. If you were involved in knocking over something which was free-standing in the first place, you can't use *drop* in a meaningful way (unless you had already pushed it halfway and were holding it up to prevent it falling completely).

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to express this is to use the expression *tip over*:

> When I leaned over too far backwards, I tipped the chair over.
>
> The chair has a shaky leg, so be careful you don't tip it over.

Comment: You can only tip a chair if you sit on it or at least are in contact with it for a while. Tipping a chair is not something you can do just by bumping into it

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan.  If you weren't already in solid contact, you would knock the chair over, not tip it over.